# Tableview inside a CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Does anyone have any experience using a tableView inside a collectionViewCell?

I have a tableview inside a collectionViewCell (each is a full screen view). Each collectionViewCell displays its own unique data. You can scroll horizontally between each collectionViewCell. The tableview has a custom tableviewCell with a couple of labels. I'm using a tableview to take advantage of the built in tableview reordering functionality.

The first collectionViewCell loads fine with data correctly showing in the tableview. However, when I scroll between collectionView cells the tableView is empty (showing only placeholder text in the labels) until the collectionViewCell stops scrolling and then the tableview suddenly appears with the correct data.

Any suggestions on how I can ensure the tableview is already populated with correct data before it's displayed? I need it to be already there as the user drags the next collectionViewCell across (just like the background image/title text is already there).

[Here's a link to my project so you can see the code.](http://www.filedropper.com/collectionviewintegration)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experience doing that.

But I think that you can reduce the problem creating a reference to your cell. So your cell won't be released. You can use an array to do that.

EDIT:

Your problem is that you are using a timer to update your label in the `TableViewCell`

You can change this:

```
if (!timer) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabels:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

for this:

```
[self updateLabels:nil];
```

and change your `updateLabels:` for this:

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSTimer *)_timer
{
    if (!timer) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabels:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    unitOfTimeLabel.text = nameOfTimeLabel;

    if ([nameOfTimeLabel isEqualToString:@"Days"]) amountOfTimeLabel.text = [self daysRemaining];
    if ([nameOfTimeLabel isEqualToString:@"Hours"]) amountOfTimeLabel.text = [self hoursRemaining];
    if ([nameOfTimeLabel isEqualToString:@"Minutes"]) amountOfTimeLabel.text = [self minutesRemaining];
    if ([nameOfTimeLabel isEqualToString:@"Seconds"]) amountOfTimeLabel.text = [self secondsRemaining];
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the collectionViewCell or tableviewCell? I need to reuse collectionViewCells as there could potentially be a lot of them and don't want to keep them in memory if possible.

Comment: I'm referring to the collectionViewCell. But if you will have many of them you need to look for another approach, maybe with a loading indicator. I don't know how you can wait for the `reloadTable` before the collection is showed...

Comment: dcorbatta you are a legend! Still trying to understand how this fixed it but it works perfect. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: I think that I can explain you why this fix the problem. Because the Timer run when the current loop finish, I mean that the timer is scheduled to run with a delay of zero, but when the loop finished. In the other hands, if you call the method in the same loop, you are ensuring these run within the same cycle.

Comment: That makes sense. I just noticed that memory usage keeps increasing as we scroll between collectionViewCells, I'm guessing because the tableview cells are not being dequeued but are being constantly loaded in via the nib. Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

in collectionviewcontroller replace this method this. Here we can dynamically set values to cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tableViewTimeDisplayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *arrayCellXib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableViewTimeDisplayCell"
                                                              owner:self
                                                            options:nil];

        cell = arrayCellXib[0];//[arrayCellXib objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setNameOfTimeLabel:cellOrderArray[indexPath.row]];//[cellOrderArray objectAtIndex:1] here we can make it as dynamic index
        [cell setEventNumber:eventNumber];
        [cell startTimer];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

// i guess the issue is when we are scrolling horizontally Tableview is allocating again and also the collection view. In collection view i have removed code other than reload tableview and pasted in initwithframe. As the view is allocating every time this will happen.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Certainly tidier code. Can you explain a bit more your last statement about pasting reload tableview in initwithframe. Yes, memory is getting eaten up with every tableview allocation. Need to fix this.